Role of missingness patterns in imputation by joint modeling
I'm interested in multiple imputation by joint modeling when all variables are incomplete. van Buuren describes the algorithm as follows:

In the critical step 10, I am confused because for any pattern $s$, this regression model is only defined for complete cases. (Note: Presumably the LHS should say $Y^{t,mis}_{[s]}$, i.e., the variables that are missing for pattern $s$, not all of $Y$. This is corroborated by the following passage:

And here, in the second expression, the $Y_1$ in the conditioning should presumably be $Y_2$. In any case, the point is that any model of the form p(some variables | all other variables) is only defined for the complete cases.)
Are the models in step 10 indeed fit using only the complete cases? That doesn't seem right because then this algorithm would be equivalent to complete-case analysis in that it is just identifying p(all variables | R=1), where R=1 denotes the complete-case pattern.
I realize that in practice, this issue could be circumvented by doing some kind of naive initial imputation, but that shouldn't change the limiting distribution that's being identified (and hence the clearly-not-true equivalence to complete-case analysis).
